# R lapply split data.table columns and reserve column names in each list element

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I would like to reserve the column names for each list element, so that column names are `C1`, `C2` and `C3` instead of `V1`. Is there a way to do it within `lapply(samp, function(...) {})`?

```
library(data.table)
samp <- data.table("C1"=letters[1:3], "C2"=letters[4:6], "C3"=letters[7:9])
samp_list <- lapply(samp, data.table)

> samp_list
$C1
   V1
1:  a
2:  b
3:  c

$C2
   V1
1:  d
2:  e
3:  f

$C3
   V1
1:  g
2:  h
3:  i
```

Ideally, something like the following. I do not really care about the list name though, in case that is helpful.

```
> samp_list
$C1
   C1
1:  a
2:  b
3:  c

$C2
   C2
1:  d
2:  e
3:  f

$C3
   C3
1:  g
2:  h
3:  i
```

Comment: @akrun works for me. Please submit your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Arun I am trying to create a package for data profiling in R. Under the function `PlotDiscrete()` (currently line 64), I am trying to pass the column name to `aes_string()` using `lapply` instead of `for` loop. GitHub link here: https://github.com/boxuancui/preprocess/blob/master/function.R#L64

Comment: The Github link is deprecated. New link is here in case anyone is interested: https://github.com/boxuancui/exploreR/blob/master/R/BarDiscrete.r#L61

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping over the colnames or the index of columns

```
lapply(seq_along(samp), function(i) samp[, ..i])
```